# Settings for file transfer via yahoo protocol on pidgin

Tags: windows-vista, file-transfer, pidgin, yahoo-messenger

OS > Windows Vista Home Premium

I have tried sending and receiving files with my friend who is using yahoo messenger but it fails every time.

Are there specific settings I should use?

-*I managed to get msn protocol to work by specifying my public ip and ports to forward.*

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could upload the file to a website such as [drop.io](http://drop.io/) (with a password) and IM the link.